# Why can static electricity discharge through someone else but not your feet?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons

How can you touch someone and then get a shock due to discharge through them?  Why don't the electrons just leave through your feet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you get the shocking problem when there is not good conduction between your feet and the ground.  The charge then builds up on your feet and conducts into your body, not the other way around.  Shoes probably make that worse, but the same thing can happen in bare feet on a carpet.

Comment: but then why doesnt the charge just leave when yiu stop moving, why is it "better" when you touch someone

Comment: The air does not conduct well, and neither does the ground if you are getting the charge buildup.  But a human is a relatively good conductor.

Comment: but say they are also wearing shoes, the electrons cant ground through them right?

Comment: The electrons never need to go into the ground, the body is serving as the charged reservoir.  Your excess electrons go into them to equate the potentials.

Answer (score 0):

The electrical "shock discharge" when you touch somebody else only occurs when your body is isolated from the ground, e.g., when you wear shoes with highly insulating sole material. Then, by triboelectricity, your body, which is a capacitor with respect to ground, can be electrically charged at a high voltage. When you touch a person or something (like a door knob) that is not electrically insulated from the ground, you can get a noticeable spark discharge. Often this phenomenon is observed under dry air conditions like in winter or in rooms with air conditioning because then the discharge of you isolated body capacitor via the conductivity of humid air is reduced.